# How to fix migration problem with missing entity plugin?

Tags: 8, migrations

I recently updated my local Drupal website from 8.3.5 to 8.3.7 on my computer. Everything runs perfect; I have no pending updated, the cache has been cleared, and to prepare the site for live deployment, it's in maintenance mode.

Om my computer, the MySQL version is 5.7.9, and PHP version is 5.6.30. I have exported all the files via FTP to the live server, exported the database, and imported it on the live server. I've altered the setting.php files to make it match with the live database credentials.

Then I went to check if there were any log messages I encountered the following PHP error:

`Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "entity" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /home/kim/domains/kimjanssens.be/public_html/carperfection/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).`

As a result of this error, after I clear my cache the whole site crashes and gives the following error messages:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidDeriverException: Plugin (entity_view) deriver "Drupal\ctools\plugin\Deriver\EntityViewDeriver" does not exist. in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDeriverClass() (line 218 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php).

Drupal\Core\Plugin\Discovery\ContainerDerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDeriver('entity_view', Array) (Line: 99)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 174)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('system_breadcrumb_block') (Line: 16)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('system_breadcrumb_block', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('system_breadcrumb_block', Array) (Line: 65)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultSingleLazyPluginCollection->initializePlugin('system_breadcrumb_block') (Line: 57)
Drupal\block\BlockPluginCollection->initializePlugin('system_breadcrumb_block') (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('system_breadcrumb_block') (Line: 45)
Drupal\block\BlockPluginCollection->get('system_breadcrumb_block') (Line: 138)
Drupal\block\Entity\Block->getPlugin() (Line: 113)
Drupal\block\BlockAccessControlHandler->checkAccess(Object, 'view', Object) (Line: 105)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->access(Object, 'view', NULL, 1) (Line: 340)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->access('view', NULL, 1) (Line: 56)
Drupal\block\BlockRepository->getVisibleBlocksPerRegion(Array) (Line: 137)
Drupal\block\Plugin\DisplayVariant\BlockPageVariant->build() (Line: 259)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 149)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 64)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 656)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: Hi Kim, you have stated a lot of facts without asking an explicit question. Could you edit the question and phrase an explicit question? I would also recommend to copy files and import database again, just to make sure no values/files were accidentally skipped during deployment.

Comment: How did you do the update ? (Please describe your process, did you use drush or ran update.php, manual file replacement or composer etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is related to ctools module. Is it still enabled/available ?

Comment: Apparently I needed to update the Ctools module, I wasn't getting an update message for it. But this might have been to old for the new 8.3.7 core update, or maybe for entity_browser that I also updated